# Reattach Rear View Mirror (No Glue Required)

Tags: kia, windshield

My driver side door didn't like the cold weather this season so I started using the other doors, and acrobatics, to place myself in the drivers seat. Through this process I kept hitting my head on my rear view mirror until eventually it came off:

**This is attached to the windshield:**

[image: Attached to windshield]

**(bottom view)**

[image: Bottom View]

**Rear view mirror connector:**

[image: Rear view mirror connector]

How do I go about re-attaching this?

The screw on the mirror doesn't fit into the metal ring. The metal ring can't be bent to allow this to happen either.

I don't see how to open the connector on the windshield. From what I could find online, it seems like you jam something into this and pry it open? What tool? Where exactly? Most, if not all, of the advice I can find online is about the proper way to glue this.

I think using a mallet might work. But I would rather not break anything or miss and break my windshield

Is my only option to try to scrape this thing off my windshield and buy a new one?

Comment: What kind of vehicle?

Comment: @Paulster2 2003 Kia Spectra

Comment: Thank you, Thank you, Thank you!!! It worked. I actually used a hammer to gently tap the bracket toward the windshield. I also found that the screw attached to the mirror is extremely tight. Be sure to use a good fitting phillips head screw driver to avoid stripping the screw while loosening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess would be that the grayish colored piece slides onto the black baseplate. It appears to be held in place by the three dimples fitting into a detent. I would insert a small screwdriver between the two humps shown in the first photo. With a twisting motion see if the gray plate slides toward the dash. You may have to try several size screwdrivers to find a size that is small enough fit in the gap and large enough to pry with. Once the gray plate is off, push  the screw through the plate and screw it in to the mirror arm. A little thread lock will prevent it from coming loose. Then slide the gray plate back over the base until it snaps in place.

Answer (score 1):

Put the edge of the screw driver on the metal circle part and give it a pop with your hand and it should slide the whole front face bracket off! This image helps people who dont quite understand how to get that cover to slide off without prying or messing it up.  The screw driver is pictured where it should be and you just use the palm of your hand to pop it off

[image: This is a picture]

Answer (score 1):

The second answer here worked for my 2005 Kia Rio. Pop the bracket off by placing a screwdriver as shown and punch it with the palm of your hand. Punch towards the front of the car.  Thanks Rich Yahtzee!

Comment: Probably better to have this as a comment under the answer you are talking about